# Passing an id through a function parameter

Tags: javascript, html, function, getelementbyid

Trying to get a value of a textbox by passing the ID into a function parameter. Should be easy but can't wrap my head around it.

JavaScript:

```
function checkfield(id) 
    {
        var field = document.getElementById(id);

        if (isNaN(field) == true) 
            {
                alert('You must enter a valid number!');
                field.value = "0";
                field.focus(textbox);
                field.select(textbox);
                return false;
            }
        return true;

    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="numbox19" name="customerZip" style="width: 240px" value=" " onchange="checkfield('numbox19')"/>
```

Error Message

> Error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Did you really mean `'numberbox19'`?  Cause your field's named "customerZip" and has the ID "19"...and it's a bit odd for a zip code field to trigger validation of another number field like that...

Comment: what do you have defined for `getValue` (you call it but it isn't shown)

Comment: @cHao Sorry for the confusion, code was updated.

Comment: @scunliffe was testing something and forgot to remove, sorry updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ID is `19`, but you're passing `numberbox19` to the Javascript function. There are also several syntax errors.

Try:

```
<input type="text" id="numberbox19" name="customerZip" style="width: 240px" value=" " onchange="checkfield(this)"/>
```

And Javascript:

```
function checkfield(field) // <-- we passed the field in directly from the HTML, using 'this'
{
    alert(field.value);

    if (isNaN(field.value)) // check the value, not the field itself!
    {
        alert('You must enter a valid number!');
        field.value = "0";
        field.focus(); // not "field.focus(textbox);"
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

The good thing here is, if you ever decide to change the ID for any reason, you only have to change it in one place instead of two.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Forgot about using this and once you posted it I got it right away.

Answer (score 2):

the id of your input is "19" not "numberbox19"